# How to implement custom component that accepts a nested component?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, components, jsx

I would like to implement a custom component that accepts a nested component. Something that can be used like this.

```
<MyCustomComponent>
  <AnyNestedComponent/>
</MyCustomComponent>
```

I searched about this but only found the use of `this.props`, which is not what I expect.

How do I implement `MyCustomComponent` in React Native version `0.68`?

**Note:** `MyCustomComponent` will consist of `View`(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its fairly simple in RN,

Your customComponent should be like =

```
const CumstomComp = ({props = {}, children = null}) => {

return(
<View style={{backgroundColor:"red"}} >

{children}

</View>

)

}
```

and then you use it like this

App.js or whatever file

```
const App = () => {

return(
<View>
 <CustomComp>
  <Flatlist />
  <View />
 </CustomComp>
</View>
)

}
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts